# black screen when I load a uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, avplayer

the issue i'm having is when i load this
UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: self.view)

it gives me a blank black view, and i don't know how to access sv variable from the button function:

let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)

im using this extintion to load the spinner and remove
http://brainwashinc.com/2017/07/21/loading-activity-indicator-ios-swift/

what im actually trying to do:

1- get url of voice message.

2- run the spinner to load the player.

3- play.

4- remove spinner if the observer find it ended.

here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func vnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vnInfo = itemss[sender.tag]
    print(vnInfo.vnUrl)
    let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
    if let url = NSURL(string: vnInfo.vnUrl) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
        player.play()
        //check if ended playing to remove spinner
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  selector:#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)


    }
}
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: self.view)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do something more like

```
private var sv : UIView?
 @IBAction func vnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vnInfo = itemss[sender.tag]
    print(vnInfo.vnUrl)
    sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
    if let url = NSURL(string: vnInfo.vnUrl) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
        player.play()
        //check if ended playing to remove spinner
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  selector:#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
    }
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    if let sv = sv {
        UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you are passing self.view here, which will remove view

UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: **self.view**) in playerDidFinishPlaying()

You need to do like, put spinnerview object outside button click,

```
var spinnerView: UIView!
```

then assign,

```
spinnerView = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
```

and while removing, **pass spinnerview not self.view**

```
UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: self.spinnerView)
```

Code will be like,

```
@IBAction func vnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
let vnInfo = itemss[sender.tag]
print(vnInfo.vnUrl)
spinnerView = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
if let url = NSURL(string: vnInfo.vnUrl) {
    player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
    player.play()
    //check if ended playing to remove spinner
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  selector:#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
}
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: self.spinnerView)
}
```

Comment: `var spinnerView = UIView()` creating empty view is useless and CPU consuming. Create options; variable instead